# SFTP server CentOS

Tags: centos, sftp

I'm trying to configure SFTP server on CentOS 7, in manner that I need to have multiple users: user1, user2, user3... all accessing only its own folder, for example:

/sftp/user1/uploads;
/sftp/user2/uploads
...

Until now, everything seams ok, but I need one admin user (sftpadmin), which can be able to be as moderator, to upload and download files to all of this folders.
I can do it with the root, but is out of the question. I need to designate some additional user to manage this job.

Answer (score 0):

The information at the following link may be useful.
https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-sftp-user-home-directories-using-chroot/

Comment: Thanks, but no good. I'm using https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-an-sftp-server-on-centos/, for initial configuration, and it works fine. However, if I add another user and change any of the permissions, to the folder structure, and even if I use 771 (for testing), all sftpusers, can't connect to their own folders.